# Execution of the Angular application in its browser window through window.open()

Tags: angular

Good afternoon!

Is there a way to launch the Angular application in my browser window - through windows.open(), so that at the end of the application I can completely close the browser window - through windows.close().
Sorry for my bad English

Regards, Mikhail

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. A window opened by the user cannot be closed by Javascript. This is a security feature added in all modern browsers. If you find a way to do it, expect it to be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but the problem with it is that it leaves a blank page open even after closing the tab.

```
    const win = window.open('about:blank','_self')
    win.top.close();
```

This is a workaround for browser to feel that its opened by the script. to avoid "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it."